# $w$ such that it contains at least 3 ones, is my approach to the CFG right?

Tags: context-free-grammar

So I was trying to solve the CFG,

$$\{w \in (0,1)^* \mid w \text{ contains at least three 1's}\}$$

My approach:

I decided that a string can begin with a $0$, end with a $0$, it may begin with a $1$, ended with a $1$, begin with a 0 end with a $1$, or begin with a $1$ and end with a $0$.

This culminates to:

$S \to 0S0 \mid 1S0 \mid 0S1 \mid 1S1 \mid 111$

Comment: Your proposed grammar seems to produce the set of all strings *of odd length* that contain at least three *consecutive* 1's in the *center* of the string.

Comment: @AndreasBlass how could I tweek it to make it work for all length?

Comment: Did you mean $w \in \{0,1\}^*$? If so, even a regular expression is enough, e.g. $\Sigma^*(1\Sigma^*)^3$ for $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is regular, so a grammar is simple to cook up starting from a DFA. Let $A$ stand for no 1 yet, $B$ for one 1, $C$ for two 1, and $D$ for three (or more) 1. Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
A &\rightarrow 0 A \mid 1 B \\
B &\rightarrow 0 B \mid 1 C \\
C &\rightarrow 0 C \mid 1 D \mid 1 \\
D &\rightarrow 0 D \mid 1 D \mid 0 \mid 1
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: This is completely wrong. You can immediately go to $D \rightarrow 0$ producing $0$ which is clearly not in the set. I don't think it is possible to make a CFG for this language.

Comment: @MiteshKumar, start symbol is $A$.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this would work:

$$ S \implies S_1aS_1aS_1aS_1 $$
$$ S_1 \implies aS_1 | bS_1 | \epsilon$$

How does this look?